# Get table-data from table-name in LINQ DataContext

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I need to get table data from table name from Linq DataContext.

Instead of this

```
var results = db.Authors;
```

I need to do something like this.

```
string tableName = "Authors";

var results = db[tableName];
```

It could be any table name that is available in DataContext.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Given `DataContext context` and `string tableName`, you can just say:

```
var table = (ITable)context.GetType()
                           .GetProperty(tableName)
                           .GetValue(context, null);
```

Comment: Ok, ITable tbl = db.GetTableByName("Authors"); how to access tbl to get the IEnumerable records?

Comment: An `ITable` is also an `IEnumerable`, so enumerate the records using your favorite method (e.g., `foreach(object r in tbl) { }`).

Comment: But it is not strongly typed. how can i cast dynamically it to get strongly typed data?

Comment: That's impossible. If you want to look up the table name dynamically then you lose the ability to have a strongly-typed table.

Comment: Why not just post the 9th line of your code example by itself? Surely anyone who needs the answer to this question is going to understand how to do null checks and what an extension method is. You are just making it harder for someone to find the useful information in your answer.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if passing strings is an elegant solution. I would rather send the Type of entity as an argument to a method. Something on these lines :

```
var table = _dataCont.GetTable(typeof(Customer));
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.gettable.aspx) is the MSDN documentation.

Comment: I need to use my string variable to get the table data.

Comment: since by design Linq2SQl does not support that. You will need to make a method that looks like Type GetTableTypeFromString(string tableName); Have a switch statement and return desired table type

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure I'd suggest it as a GOOD solution, but if you really need it, you could do something like this:

```
MyDBContext db = new MyDBContext();
Type t = db.GetType();
PropertyInfo p = t.GetProperty("Authors");
var table = p.GetValue(db, null);
```

That will give you the Authors table, as pr. Table.

Comment: This will type `table` as an `object`; you need to cast to an `ITable` before use.

Comment: Can you provide how to Use ITable to get data as IEnumerable or IQueryable?

Comment: It is already both an IEnumerable/IQueryable. The difference is it is not the generics version IEnumerable<T>/IQueryable<T>, so you can't use strongly typed queries on it. But you can use Dynamic linq to perform weakly typed queries. More information here: http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Dynamic-LINQ.aspx and download it here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpsamples/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=8 (You're looking for dynamic.cs)

Comment: ITable tbl = db.GetTableByName("Authors");
var data = (from m in tbl select m).ToList();

I tried this way... but getting compile error : Error 1 Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Data.Linq.ITable'.  'Select' not found.  Consider explicitly specifying the type of the range variable 'm'.

Comment: Hi. You can't use it this way. Like I said, you cannot use strongly typed queries here, so you would have to do a foreach(var tblrow in tbl) {} to iterate and perform if's on each element. Or, you can maybe look at Dynamic Linq.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the type, you can cast it. From http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f5e5f3c8-ac3a-49c7-8dd2-e248c8736ffd/using-variable-table-name-in-linq-syntax?forum=linqprojectgeneral

```
MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext();
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
Type t = assembly.GetType("Namespace." + strTableName);
if (t != null)
{
    var foos = db.GetTable(t);

    foreach (var f in foos)
    {
        PropertyInfo pi = f.GetType().GetProperty("Foo");
        int value = (int)pi.GetValue(f, null);
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```