# LINQPad: How to get row count in a table using MetaTable type?

Tags: .net, linqpad

In LINQPad, I'm trying to print all tables in a database and row count in each of them:

```
this.Mapping.GetTables().Select(o => new { TableName = o.TableName, RowCount = ? })
```

How the row count can be calculated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a need to do the same thing and I was looking ONLY the tables that contained data.  I found out pretty quickly that you have to be careful of what you pull back from here because the data is deeply nested.  The query below took less than a second to run on my machine and I have approximately 266 tables (not including views) in the database.
I hope that this answers your question.

```
 var list = this.Mapping.GetTables()    
     .Select(o => new { 
    TableName = o.TableName, 
    Type_ = o.RowType.Type, 
    IsEntity = o.RowType.IsEntity,
    RowCount = this.GetTable(o.RowType.Type).Cast<object>().Count(),
    })
    .Where (o => o.IsEntity && o.RowCount > 0)
    .ToList();

 list.Dump();
```

Answer (score 2):

```cs
this.Mapping.GetTables().Select(o => new { 
    TableName = o.TableName, 
    RowCount = (
        (IEnumerable<object>)this.GetType().GetProperty(
            o.TableName.Substring(1, o.TableName.Length-2)
    ).GetValue(this, null))
    .Count()
}).Dump();
```

Kudos to [this answer from Jason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1924966/209103) for showing how to look up a table by name.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var list = this.Mapping.GetTables()
    .Select(o => new { TableName = o.TableName, Type_ = o.Row.Type, RowCount = 0 }).ToList();

list.ForEach(x=>x.RowCount  = this.GetTable(x.Type_).Count);
list.Select(o=> new { TableName = o.TableName, RowCount = 0 });
```

Comment: That is flat-out not good. Why would you want to send a direct SQL statement through to the DB and bypass all the strong type checking available with Linq queries?

Comment: Hes using LinqPad not a production system, its a sandbox.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Still a bad suggestion. That is sloppy programming, and doesn't address the issue.

Answer (score 0):

## Try this:

```
var list = from o in this.Mapping.GetTables()
let rowCount = ExecuteQuery<int>("select count(*) from "+ o.TableName).FirstOrDefault()
 select new {
    TableName = o.TableName,
        RowCount = rowCount
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Or without using Mapping :

```
this.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.DeclaringType == typeof(TypedDataContext)).Select(t => new 
{ 
    TableName = t.Name,
    RowCount = ((IEnumerable<object>)(this.GetType().GetProperty(t.Name).GetValue(this, null))).Count()
}).Dump();
```

Answer (score -4):

This is not a LinqPad issue, but rather a Linq issue. But let me give you a nice LinqPad tip. Add .Dump() to your query and see what you get - very cool.

```
this.Mapping.GetTables().Select(o => new { TableName = o.TableName, RowCount = ? }).Dump()
```

Comment: How adding Dump help here? I know the Dump method and know it's very cool, but how it's relates to this question?

Comment: I don't get how the Dump can help here? Where should I add it to see what you are talking about?