# how to set entity framework table name at runtime in linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

In my mvc 4, EF 6 application I need to set the table/entity name at runtime and pull the data using dynamic linq queries. I have seen [ScottGu's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library) explaining the dynamic queries but on the top of this I need to set the table/entity name dynamically too. I have also found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032228/how-can-i-dynamically-select-my-table-at-runtime-with-dynamic-linq) on SOF which is using Linq to sql to achieve what I need to do in EF. I can't replicate this as `DataContext.GetTable(entityType)` not available in EF.

```
 GazMatchingEntities entities=new GazMatchingEntities();
 entities.runtimeEntityname.where(....)
```

I will appreciate any examples or ideas. thanks

Comment: You can use `DbContext.Set(Type entityType)`.

Comment: @tia thanks for the comment. It does help but I m getting an error on this line and wonder if you've any ideas ` string  tablename = "CentraladdrcdoQueries"; string typeName="entities."+tablename; var entityType=Type.GetType(typeName);` and the entityType is always null

Comment: Are the types in your main assembly? Otherwise you need an assemblyQualifiedName for them in the `Type.GetType(..)` call

Comment: I have only one project named  SFRS.GazMatching.Web and it has EF .edmx files  so I have tried something like this `string typeName = "entities." + tablename+",SFRS.GazMatching.Web";` but the value is still null