# c# set DataContext column values without strongly typing it

Tags: c#, datacontext

```
        //Instead of the this 
        var tableX = db.PRODUCT; //db is the DataContext
        //I can do the below (Thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919632/get-table-data-from-table-name-in-linq-datacontext
        string tablename = "PRODUCT";
        var table = (ITable)db.GetType().GetProperty(tablename).GetValue(db, null);

        //But instead of this
        PRODUCT _Product = new PRODUCT();
        _Product.PRD_CODE = "code1";
        _Product.PRD_DESC = "description1";
        table.InsertOnSubmit(_Product);
        db.SubmitChanges();

        //How can I do something like this
        string tablename = "PRODUCT";
        var table = (ITable)db.GetType().GetProperty(tablename).GetValue(db, null);
        string lsColumnPrdCode = "PRD_CODE";
        string lsColumnPrdDesc = "PRD_DESC";
        table _tableInstance = new table();
        _tableInstance[lsColumnPrdCode] = "code1";
        _tableInstance[lsColumnPrdDesc] = "description1";
        _tableInstance.InsertOnSubmit(_tableInstance);
        db.SubmitChanges();
```

So it is possible to set datacontext column values without strongly typing it?

Comment: That is definitely possible. After all, C# is a reflexive language. We've done that in our project. But that is too much of code. I'm feeling tired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of cause you can use reflection to do that kind of stuff. Maybe something similar to this code:

```
Type productType = Type.GetType("PRODUCT");
var product = Activator.CreateInstance(productType);
productType.GetProperty("PRD_CODE").SetValue(product, "code1");
productType.GetProperty("PRD_DESC").SetValue(product, "description1");

Type tableType = table.GetType();
tableType.GetMethod("InsertOnSubmit").Invoke(table, new object[] {product});
```

But why do you want to do that?

Comment: Thanks Jan. I have 50+ tables which has reference data and this data gets refreshed from values taken from a XML (downloaded via the webservices). The table and column names are the the element names in the XML and instead of having to type one routine per table, I was hoping to make it generic, so one routine will handle all tables based on the XML element name. I have done this in c# (using DataTable and TabelDirect commands) without DataContext and in Java (Android based) and wanted to do the same in WindowsPhone 7. I am using XmlReader to read.

Comment: Type productType = db.GetType().GetProperty("PRODUCT").GetValue(db, null).GetType(); var product = Activator.CreateInstance(productType); //Throws no parameterless constructor found error (methodmissingexception) //So tried... var ctor = productType.GetConstructor(new Type[] { }); var obj = ctor.Invoke(new object[] { }); //Still error, as ctor value is null. Any suggestions?

Comment: If your PRODUCT-class has no parameterless constructor, you have to specify parameter values in the `CreateInstance` call.

Comment: Thanks Jan. Your initial code is the correct answer. What I had missed was that, in the first line I had to type in the fully qualified assembly name instead of just "PRODUCT", so it was something like "MYASSEMBLY.PRODUCT". Once I did that, it worked prefectly. Thanks for your help.