# Setting a dynamic Linq 'where' clause in an iTable

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, devexpress, itable

I have to set a LinqDataSource dynamically. According to the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919632/get-table-data-from-table-name-in-linq-datacontext) 
My code looks like this at the moment:

```
DataContext context = (DataContext)Activator
                      .CreateInstance(Type.GetType("namespace.Table1DataContext"));
ITable table = (ITable)context.GetType()
                      .GetProperty("NameOfTableInContext").GetValue(context, null);
```

Now I need to set a dynamic filter (where) because the columns can change where we want to filter)
I`ve tried something like this:

```
var result = from DataRow myRow in table 
             where myRow.Field<int>("ColumnName") == 14972 select myRow;
```

And then Assigning it to the LinqServerModeDataSource (DevExpress)

```
e.QueryableSource = result
```

If I assign the table direct to the QueryableSource, it works and it shows everything. But if i try to put the result into it, it has no entrys. Does anyone have an idea how i can set a where clause or Filter to it (or maybe an other idea)?