# Enumerating a LINQ-to-SQL DataContext

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am looking to enumerate through all the tables in the DataContext I have created using the O/R Designer.

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919632/get-table-data-from-table-name-in-linq-datacontext), I'm presently using reflection to do so, i.e.

```
PropertyInfo[] dc_properties = data.GetType().GetProperties(); //data is DataContext
PropertyInfo[] row_properties;

foreach (var prop in dc_properties)
{
  object value = prop.GetValue(data);

  if(value is ITable)
  {
    var table = (ITable)value; //value is a table

    foreach (var item in table) //item is a row in the table
    {
      row_properties = item.GetType().GetProperties(); //row_properties values of a row
      foreach (var prop2 in row_properties) 
      {
        object value2 = prop2.GetValue(item); //prop2 a value
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, this is very slow. Does anybody know a better way to enumerate through a DataContext and obtain the values of all the rows of all the tables in it?

Thank you.

Comment: I do hope you comprehend what you want to do... You want to get all the data of the DB... yes?

Comment: @xanatos yes, exactly.

Comment: You can optimize a little the Get of the single properties (even because not all the properties could be mapped to the DB)... But I'm not sure it would change very much.

Comment: @xanatos so you know of no better way to achieve this enumeration?

Comment: In the most general case, supporting [Inheritance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb399352(v=vs.100).aspx), I'm not sure you can speed up very much... What do you want to do with the data then? Put in `object[]` for each row? Save it to a CSV?

Comment: @xanatos I need to be able to pull out all of the data of a DB at runtime. I think I may have been wrong to think that LINQ-to-SQL could do it - possibly using the SqlConnection class would be a better choice.

Comment: Yes... It would be much faster. An `SqlDataReader` would be much better. The only problem is that you would have to retrieve the table names, but if you look around there should be commands to retrieve table names from the DB

Comment: @xanatos thank you for your input - I look into SqlDataReader!

Comment: You'll also want to look at `SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables` to know what to start off with.

Comment: @JonHanna thanks ... I've found the SqlConnection.GetSchema which is proving useful.