# How to fetch table records by table name?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using entity framework 6 code first approach.

At some point I get from the user a string, table name and column name.

I need to fetch records using table name and column name.

Any idea how can I implement it using LINQ?

Comment: Please refer old solution which might be solve your problem :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919632/get-table-data-from-table-name-in-linq-datacontext

Comment: @Hemdip,nice solution.Any idea what is ITable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the Hemdip link, you can use reflection to get what you want :

```
var table = (IEnumerable)context.GetType().GetProperty(tableName).GetValue(context, null);

List<object> results = new List<object>();

foreach(var line in table)
{
    var value = line.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(line, null);

    if(value == searchValue) {
        results.Add(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a interface representing a database table. This is not usefull for this example. I update my answer consequently.

Comment: I get error :Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: On which line ? Are you sure that a table named like `tableName` exists in your database ? Same question for the column.

Comment: Table name or name of the entity in context?

Comment: for this line:

_context.GetType().GetProperty("Client").GetValue(_context, null);
I get error above.

Comment: Paul,it seems that I set a wrong table name.Now I get records from table.But I get exception in second row: table.GetType().GetProperty("Id").GetValue(table, null).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot a part in my example. The first line allows you to recover the table. Then you can browse the table to get the element(s) to recover. You can then use the second line of my example, to recover the correct property, using the column name. Do you know the type of the elements contained in the table ?

Comment: It's can be string or Date or int

Comment: I updated my answer, please look and tell me if that suits you.

Comment: Do you have any idea why in this row :
 var value = line.GetType().GetProperty("Id").GetValue(table, null); 
I get this exception:
Object does not match target type.

Comment: You are using exactly the same code ? Try to separate the line too see from which part the exception comes from (`var type = line.GetType();`  `var property = type.GetProperty("Id");`, etc..

Comment: I get it on this row: var property = type.GetProperty("Id");

Comment: I found the error : The GetValue method was called with the "table" object,  instead of the "line" object. Correction (I update my answer) : `var value = line.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(line, null);`