# Linq Dynamic table

Tags: linq, dynamic

There's a way in linq to use a string to call a table ? i tried linq dynamic but didn't find what i was looking for. So basically i will have a string that i pass in a parameter and i will use it to call my table :

ex :

```
public IEnumerable<Category> SearchInTable(string table)

var context = new MapEntities() ;

myTable = context.Tables[table]; // something like that. Table == Country

return myTable.Where(x => x.name.Contains("Canada")).OrderByDescending(o => o.id).Take(10);
```

i hope i was clear ! thank you

Comment: What data access technology are you using? Entity Framework?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get table-data from table-name in LINQ DataContext](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919632/get-table-data-from-table-name-in-linq-datacontext)

Answer (score 0):

```
public IQueryable<Category> SearchInTable(string table)
{
  var context = new MapEntities();
  IQueryable<Category> myTable;
  switch(table)
  {
    case "Canada": myTable=context.Canada; break;
    case "UnitedStates": myTable=context.UnitedStates; break;
    else throw new Exception("Table not found");
  }
  return myTable.Where(x => x.name.Contains("Canada")).OrderByDescending(o => o.id).Take(10);
}
```

Although you probably should break this apart:

```
public static IQueryable<Category> GetTable(this DataContext context,string table)
{
  IQueryable<Category> myTable;
  switch(table)
  {
    case "Canada": myTable=context.Canada; break;
    case "UnitedStates": myTable=context.UnitedStates; break;
    else throw new Exception("Table not found");
  }
  return myTable;
}

public static IQueryable<Category> Search(this IQueryable<Category> context)
{
  return context.Where(x => x.name.Contains("Canada")).OrderByDescending(o => o.id).Take(10);
}
```

then you can do this:

```
var result=new MapEntities().GetTable("Canada").Search();
```

(I probably wouldn't put the .Take(10) in Search either, and I'd come up with a better name, like ContainsCanada, or make search a bit more generic)

Comment: There's a way to do it without a switch case ? Let's say i will have 50 tables having the same structure, so i don't want to use 50 case.

Comment: If you have 50 tables all with the same structure, then you probably should have designed it as one table with an additional column with a FK into a second table.

Comment: For performance concerns, i prefer to have my table separately. I dont want to go through all the table containing 50 categories to get the one i need. Plus each category can have different rows. If i use one table its much faster. ex : If category == country then get data from the country table, etc

Comment: Have you actually checked the performance difference? Because I'm guessing you won't be able to measure it.  As for having to go through all of the table to get to the one you want, that's what indexes are for.  You shouldn't be doing a full table scan.

Comment: I agree.  It's obvious that you won't be able to measure the difference because the vast majority of queries you issue should be using an index, and if you build the same index using your additional column, it will result in a binary tree lookup in memory which will be likely be immeasurably different in speed.  However, what you will find is that if you are issuing the same query across multiple of these tables, you've now generated 50 different query plans, plans that now have to be searched through for every query (or have been dropped because there isn't room) for negative performance.

Comment: Or 50 different query plans that must be built for each individual table, rather than just reusing the one it already has.  Feel free to test it, or not.  Premature false microoptimization isn't good.

Comment: I will always use one query at a time. If a user choose Country in a dropdown list it will query the Country table and list all the countries in that table, if he choose City it will query the City table and list all the cities in that table, etc. So if i have 50 items in my dropdown list (country, city, province, etc), i will always query one table at a time. But still, i'm sure it should be a way to just use and fetch the table sent in param without using condition "case" or "if". Thank you for all your help so far.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97419/discussion-between-user708683-and-robert-mckee).