# Use type derived from GetType() without using Switch

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, gridview, reusability

I am using Entity Framework and LINQ. I want to create a reusable method in a "helper" class for GridViews.

The method will return a DataSource as a List of entities based off the type of entity passed.

So GridView1 will show [Entity1]'s so the call will look like:

```
GridView1.DataSource = helperClass.GetDataSource(new Entity1());
```

Note* If I should pass the entity type I want as a string in the method I am open for suggestion. I just don't want to have to use a switch case between the ~40 entity types this method could return

The reusable method will be simple and look similar to:

```
public static object GetDataSource(object type)
{
    using (DatabaseContext dc = new DatabaseContext())
    {
        if (dc.[how do I get the entity type here].Count() > 0)
        {
            var modelList = dc.[how do I get the entity type here also].ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

This will sound silly, but obviously I wasn't able to do:

```
var modelList = dc.(type.GetType()).ToList();
```

but that is basically what I want to accomplish.

Comment: What good does that do you? You get a list of objects back but don't know their type at compile time? I suspect there's a better way to do what you want with generics.

Comment: That said, this is close to a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919632, with the difference that you need to get the name from the type first.

Comment: @DStanley There very well may be. This was just the first approach I thought of when trying to make a reusable helper method. I have a web app with multiple GridViews with similar methods (like sort, bind, and databound) so I wanted to make reusable methods in a remote class for these methods rather than type the same code (with the variance of what entity is shown for the GridView) ~40 times

Comment: Check the duplicate, which uses a string instead of a type, but uses reflection to "find" the corresponding property.  It's not elegant and breaks type safety, but will do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach was not plausible and I ended up storing the datasource of the GridView in a SessionState variable. Saved having to requery for the DataSource each postback (could get tedious if I had to keep track of order bys when requerying. instead the sessionstate variable keeps the sort order)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind the type at compile-time, you can pass the type as a generic argument, and use this type of method:

```
        public DbSet<T> GetDataSource<T>()
        {
            var targetType = typeof(DbSet<T>);

            return _db
                .GetType()
                .GetMethods()
                .Where( m => m.ReturnType == targetType)
                .Single()
                .Invoke(_db, null) as DbSet<T>;
        }
```

How does it work? Well, we don't know the name of the method that returns the entity that is being requested, but we do know that the return type has to be a `DbSet<T>`. So we scan the DatabaseContext for any method that returns that type, and invoke it. This assumes there is exactly one method that has that return type.

If you need true run-time binding (you can't supply the `<T>` parameter) you can use this sort of method. Note that the return type is just a general `IEnumerable` because you can't have a specific return type if it's not known at compile time. You can always cast it back to a `DbSet<T>` if needed.

```
        public IEnumerable GetDataSource(Type type)
        {
            var targetType = typeof(DbSet<>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] { type });

            return _db
                .GetType()
                .GetMethods()
                .Where( m => m.ReturnType == targetType)
                .Single()
                .Invoke(_db, null) as IEnumerable;
        }
```

Here is a full example. Note that I stubbed out the EF objects, but this example should still work with a real `DbSet` and `DatabaseContext`.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{

    public class DbSet<T> : List<T>
    {
    }

    public class User
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "User " + Name;
        }
    }

    public class Transaction
    {
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "Transaction " + Amount.ToString("0.00");
        }
    }

    public class DatabaseContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> GetUsers() 
        {
            return new DbSet<User>()
            {
                new User { Name = "Bob" },
                new User { Name = "Alice" }
            };
        }
        public DbSet<Transaction> GetTransactions() 
        {
            return new DbSet<Transaction>()
            {
                new Transaction { Amount = 12.34M },
                new Transaction { Amount = 56.78M }
            };
        }

    }

    public class HelperClass
    {
        private readonly DatabaseContext _db;

        public HelperClass(DatabaseContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        public DbSet<T> GetDataSource<T>()
        {
            var targetType = typeof(DbSet<T>);

            return _db
                .GetType()
                .GetMethods()
                .Where( m => m.ReturnType == targetType)
                .Single()
                .Invoke(_db, null) as DbSet<T>;
        }

        public IEnumerable GetDataSource(Type type)
        {
            var targetType = typeof(DbSet<>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] { type });

            return _db
                .GetType()
                .GetMethods()
                .Where( m => m.ReturnType == targetType)
                .Single()
                .Invoke(_db, null) as IEnumerable;
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var helperClass = new HelperClass(new DatabaseContext());

        foreach (var u in helperClass.GetDataSource<User>())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(u);
        }

        foreach (var t in helperClass.GetDataSource(typeof(Transaction)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(t);
        }

    }
}
```

Output:

```
User Bob
User Alice
Transaction 12.34
Transaction 56.78
```

[Full code on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ocNxoK)